# System.AggregateException in Program.cs in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which uses Entity Framework Core O/RM. I am implementing generic repository pattern in my application. There are two entities, `Employee` & `Department`. There is one context class `EmployeeDepartmentDetails`.There's an interface `IGenericRepository` which is implemented by `GenericRepository`. `GenericRepository` has a Dependency Injection of `EmployeeDepartmentDetails`.My Controller `EmployeeController` has a Dependency Injection of `IGenericRepository`.

IGenericRepository.cs -

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //...
}
```

GenericRepository.cs - Here `EmployeeDepartmentDetails` is my context class which inherits `DBContext` class-

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> :IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    // Dependency Injection 
    private readonly EmployeeDepartmentDetail _employeeDepartmentDetail; 
    public GenericRepository(EmployeeDepartmentDetail employeeDepartmentDetail)
    {
        _employeeDepartmentDetail = employeeDepartmentDetail;
        _dbSet = _employeeDepartmentDetail.Set<TEntity>();
    } 

    //... 
}
```

Program.cs -

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); // I am getting those two exceptions here
}
```

StartUp.cs -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<Type>), typeof(GenericRepository<Type>)); 
}
```

EmployeeController.cs -

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Employee> _genericRepository;
    public EmployeeController(IGenericRepository<Employee> genericRepository)
    {
        _genericRepository = genericRepository;
    } 

    //... 
}
```

I am getting two exception, when I am running my application -

> System.AggregateException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Interface.IGenericRepository`1[System.Type] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Implementation.GenericRepository`1[System.Type]': A suitable constructor for type 'InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Implementation.GenericRepository`1[System.Type]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.)
>     Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
>     StackTrace:at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider() at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build() at CrudEfCore.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\singh\Desktop\MVC\GenericRepository\CrudEfCore\Program.cs:line 16
>   This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:[External Code]
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Interface.IGenericRepository`1[System.Type] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Implementation.GenericRepository`1[System.Type]': A suitable constructor for type 'InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Implementation.GenericRepository`1[System.Type]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'InfrastructureLayer.GenericRepository.Implementation.GenericRepository`1[System.Type]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

I am unable to understand the exception, I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I know I have pasted lot of code, but I don't even know how to explain the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cause of the issue

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<Type>), typeof(GenericRepository<Type>));
```

`Type` is an abstract class and as the error message states:

> Ensure the type is **concrete** and services are registered for all parameters of a **public constructor**.

note: emphasis mine

Next `Type` is not what you should be using as the generic argument when registering the generic service

In this case you can register using (generic) open types, eliminating the need to register every (generic) constructed type:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Can you explain your answer ? I still didn't understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Nihal, to understand working with generics better, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) would be a good place to start.